# Kernel module to intercept voip stream

Tags: c++, linux-kernel, sip, voip

my issue is like this:
i want to developp a kernel module to intercept voip stream and do the same what a SBC(Session Border Controller) do.
So i must first of all intrcept voip stream and then work on session layer in the packages.
So any one can help me ?

Comment: Allahu akbar. What operating system? You shouldn't need to develop a kernel module for this

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: Step 1) answer my question above. Step 2) ...

Comment: my operating system is xubuntu 64 bits

Comment: For linux, you can use the [TUN/TAP device driver](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt)

Answer (score 0):

To intercept network stream you do not really need kernel module. Make user space app using BSD sockets or if you familiar with C++ you can try boost.asio
If you want to receive raw datagrams (non tcp/udp traffic) use SOCK_RAW type.

Comment: i wanna intercept the voip stream to make some modification inside sip packet like the public address of my asterisk server so that no one outside my local network knows the real public address of the server, it's basics of the sessiion border controller.

Comment: SIP is over tcp and I assume you do not need modify tcp header, if so open listen SOCK_STREAM socket, accept and call read on the socket - you will get a buffer which would contain you sip content, once you have it you can modify it, send it to file or other socket

Comment: is there a code that allow me to listen and modify to SOCK_STREAM socket ?